# Problem with finding a limit of a tricky function

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Find the limit 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ 1}{x \sqrt{x} } \int_{0}^{x} \ln \frac{t^{3} + 2}{t^{2} +1 } dt $$

A hint that has been given is to use L'Hospital's Rule. Moreover, it must be substantiated why we can use L'Hospital' Rule in this situation.

Comment: Try to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Answer (score 1):

1. $\frac{ 1}{x \sqrt{x} } \int_{0}^{x} \ln \frac{t^{3} + 2}{t^{2} +1 } dt =\frac{\int_{0}^{x} \ln \frac{t^{3} + 2}{t^{2} +1 }dt}{x \sqrt{x}}$
2. If $F(x):= \int_{0}^{x} \ln \frac{t^{3} + 2}{t^{2} +1 } dt $, then $F'(x)= \ln \frac{x^{3} + 2}{x^{2} +1 } $

Answer (score 1):

It can be performed straight away like this:
\begin{align}
I
&=
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{1}{x \sqrt{x} }
\int_{0}^{x} 
\ln \frac{t^3 + 2}{ t^2 + 1} d t 
=
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{
\int_{0}^{x} 
\ln \frac{t^3 + 2}{ t^2 + 1} d t 
}{x \sqrt{x} }
~~
\overset{formed  ~ \frac{\infty}{\infty}}{=}
~~
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{ 
\left(
\int_{0}^{x} 
\ln \frac{t^3 + 2}{ t^2 + 1} d t 
\right)' _x
}{ (x \sqrt{x})' _x }
\\
&=
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{
\ln \frac{x^3 + 2}{ x^2 + 1} 
}{ \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{x} }
~~
\overset{formed  ~ \frac{\infty}{\infty}}{=}
~~
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{
\left( \ln \frac{x^3 + 2}{ x^2 + 1} \right)'_x
}{ \left( \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{x} \right)'_x }
\\
&=
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{
\frac{ x^2 + 1}{x^3 + 2}
\frac{ x^4 + 3x^2 - 4x }{ x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 }
}{ \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} }
=
\frac{4}{3}
\lim_{x \to \infty} 
\frac{ \sqrt{x} ( x^2 + 1 ) }{x^3 + 2}
\frac{ x^4 + 3x^2 - 4x }{ x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 }
= 
0
\end{align}
where we applied L'Hospital's Rule twice due to the limits in form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as $x>2$, over the interval $(0,x)$ the function $\log\frac{t^3+2}{t^2+1}$ is bounded by $\log x$.
It follows that
$$ \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}\int_{0}^{x}\log\frac{t^3+2}{t^2+1}\,dt \leq \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}} $$
and the wanted limit is trivially zero by squeezing.